# C++, Namespaces, Templates, and No Matching Function Call

Tags: c++, templates, generics, namespaces

I've checked similar tags but I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to use the CImg library and it's my first time working with templates in C++. 
I'm in the process of porting some of my image processing stuff to work with this library and I've run into a bit of trouble. Hopefully someone here can set me straight! 
I have a main file where I'm playing around with CImg to see what it can do, right now I'm just using it as a sandbox. I've created a header file with some template functions (since my .cpp files didn't work correctly) which includes my library (**CN**) and the **CImg** library. The template functions I created work with no issues unless they also use the **CN** library. That is,
`cn_cimg_get_RGBtoGray(tinyImg)` works as intended. I'm getting the following from gcc
`main.cpp:54: error: no matching function for call to 'cn_cimg_get_CNtoCImg(CN::cnImage&)`
When I compile with 
`g++ -Icn -Icimg  -o cimg.bin main.cpp cn/cn_matrix.cpp cn/cn_image.cpp \
-lpthread -lX11 -lgdi32`

Below is the relevant code; or so I hope.

Here is my *main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "cn_image.h"
#include "cn_cimg.hpp"
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace CN;

int main(int argv, char **argc) {

 cout << "MAIN RUNNING" << endl;    
 srand( time(NULL) );

 // Create CImg Stuff (New)
 CImg<unsigned char> tinyImg("16x16.gif");
 CImg<unsigned char> gray = cn_cimg_get_RGBtoGray(tinyImg);

 // Create cnImage (Old)
 cnImage cn;
 cn_create(&cn, tinyImg.width(), tinyImg.height());

 // Copy tinyImg to cn manually
 cimg_forXY(tinyImg, x, y){
    cn.r.data[x][y] = tinyImg(x, y, CHANNEL_R);
    cn.g.data[x][y] = tinyImg(x, y, CHANNEL_G);
    cn.b.data[x][y] = tinyImg(x, y, CHANNEL_B);
 }  

 // Create new CImg and try conversion function
 CImg<unsigned char> fromCN = cn_cimg_get_CNtoCImg(cn);

 // Check if fromCN is tinyImg
 fromCN.display();

 // Clean up cnImage Memory
 cn_destroy(&cn);
 return 0;
}
```

Here is *cn_cimg.hpp*

```
#include "cn_image.h"
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

namespace CN {

static const int CHANNEL_R = 0;
static const int CHANNEL_G = 1;
static const int CHANNEL_B = 2;

// Converts RGB to GrayScale and Returns a new CImg
template <class CImg>
CImg cn_cimg_get_RGBtoGray(const CImg& img)
{
    // Create Single Channel (Gray) Image
    CImg temp(img.width(), img.height(), 1);

    cimg_forXY(img, x, y)
    {
        temp(x, y) = ( img(x, y, CHANNEL_R) + img(x, y, CHANNEL_G) + img(x, y, CHANNEL_B) ) / 3.0f;
    }

    return temp;    
}

    // cnImage to CImage conversions
template <class CImg>
CImg cn_cimg_get_CNtoCImg(const cnImage &cn) 
{
    // Confirm cnImage has stuff
    if(!cn_isAlloc(&cn))
    {
        // If not, return basic CImg
        CImg cimg(1,1,1,3);
        return cimg;
    }

    // Create a CImg with 3 Channels (RGB)
    CImg cimg(cn.rgb.cols, cn.rgb.rows, 1, 3);

    // Copy the Channels
    cimg_forXY(cimg, x, y)
    {
        cimg(x, y, CHANNEL_R) = cn.r.data[x][y];
        cimg(x, y, CHANNEL_G) = cn.g.data[x][y];
        cimg(x, y, CHANNEL_B) = cn.b.data[x][y];
    }
    return cimg;
}    
}
```

I really have no idea why I can't match the functions but I usually run into these troubles when doing something for the first time. Also, if anyone sees any bad style or whatnot in my templates I'll gladly take some criticism. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can't deduce template parameters solely from the return type. You have the supply the template parameter explicitly in this case:

```
CImg<unsigned char> fromCN = cn_cimg_get_CNtoCImg<CImg<unsigned char> >(cn);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Is this because there no CImg being input so there's no way for it to know what type of generic to return?

Comment: Exactly. You have the liberty to convert your cnImage to a CImg of any type. The compiler does not know which one.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly instantiating the template:

```
    CImg<unsigned char> fromCN = cn_cimg_get_CNtoCImg< CImg<unsigned char> >(cn);
```

EDIT: Argh! beaten by 13 seconds.

Comment: I still thank you nonetheless. I dunno how long it would have taken me to stumble onto this.

Comment: Yeah, but I was just 1 rep shy of hitting the 200 limit for the day, so was figuring that I'd try to push a little bit more to get it before signing off.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the templated value because the compiler can't deduce it from return value:

method defined:

```
template <class CImg>
CImg cn_cimg_get_CNtoCImg(const cnImage &cn)
```

need to call:

```
CImg<unsigned char> fromCN = cn_cimg_get_CNtoCImg( CImg<unsigned char> )(cn);
```

It's confusing because the template parameter is called CImg, it is more clear if you rename it to T for example just to see the difference:

```
template <class T>
T cn_cimg_get_CNtoCImg(const cnImage &cn);
```